# Is it possible to create a Tag while committing and pushing the change

Tags: git, gradle, gradle-plugin, grgit

Is it possible to create a Tag in git while committing and pushing the change using the grgit plugin ...??

This is my code to push my changes to git ..

```
task pushChangestoGit()
{
    def grgit = org.ajoberstar.grgit.Grgit.open(dir: '.')
    grgit.add(patterns: ['version.properties'])
    grgit.commit(message: 'Committing Version Property Changes')
    grgit.push(force: true)
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by creating a tag while committing and pushing? Tag as part of the commit and before push, or tag simultaneously using different terminal?

Comment: Thanks @ Crazyjavahacking .. I just want to know is it possible to create a tag using gr git plugin for gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it by:

```
grgit.tag.add(name: 'tag-name', pointsTo: 'changeset')
```